# Unix ksh validation

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

```
echo banana apple pear grape melon orange lime
read fruit1 fruit2 fruit3
```

Questions:
- How to test if the user input 3 arguments and not less?
- How to test if the 3 arguments are in the list or if it is 3 out of these seven?

I read many things on the internet, I tried playing with s#, nothing is working.

Comment: I have another question with all the codes I tried, but as noone has a solution, I am posting the plain question to see if someone would get less confused with the plain question, please see my other question to the codes, I have tried. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i=0
for var in "banana apple pear grape melon orange lime read fruit1 fruit2 fruit3"
if [ "$var" == "$2" -o "$var" == "$3" -o "$var" == "$4" ]
then
++$i
fi


echo $i
```

if value of i is 3 then it means all the three command line arguments are present.

Comment: Sorry about that comment, but how can this script that doesn't even execute and after being fixed, doesn't either answer to the question asked can be upvoted and accepted ?